# calculate the min of a table grouped by a unique id - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, min

I need a help with a query.

```
select *,min(cast(hour(now())- hour_offer) as unsigned))  as time_left 
       from out_of_offer 
       group by offer_id 
       order by time_left asc
```

I have multiple hour_offer in my out_of_offer table and I need to get only one record (grouped by offer_id) that is closest to the current hour.

for example

```
offer_id           hour(now())            hour_offer
    1                 11                   8
    2                 11                   9
    1                 11                   10
    2                 11                   11
    2                 11                   12
```

what I want my query to do is to get the 3rd and 4th rows because they are the closest to the current hour (11) and they have different offer_ids.

```
hour_offer is mediumint(2) unsigned
```

can anybody help me how to do that?

**EDIT**
if I print out `hour(now())-hour_offer` in the mysql query the result is an huge (positive) number.

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Er, no it isn't, and why is 10 closer to 11 than 12?

Comment: they have different ids so it doesn't matter. in the case they have the same id, it's not important at this point if the query gives one or another.

Comment: sorry. the primary key is called differently. I should call id as offer. see changes. now id(now hidden) is the primary key

Comment: What is you data time type 12 hours OR 24 hours? is your DB has same setting?

Comment: my data time type is 24 hours. I filled the hour_offer field as a 24 hours type too.

Comment: before this query I set time_zone="+2:00"

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo Check the answer, I guess this is what you want.

Comment: Given that hour_offer appears to be UNIQUE, would it not make a good candidate key?

Comment: @Strawberry it could be present the row ('offer_id','hour_offer') as (2,10) so the hour_offer is not considered as a key.

LucasHarada I will try your solution and let u know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM out_of_offer o,
(SELECT offer_id, MIN(ABS(hour-hour_offer)) AS diff FROM out_of_offer
GROUP BY offer_id) x
WHERE o.offer_id = x.offer_id AND ABS(o.hour-o.hour_offer) = x.diff;
```

I guess is better use `ABS` isntead of `CAST`. I don't know exactly why, but your syntax on `CAST` is wrong.

You may change de `hour` for `hour(now)`. I used `hour` to test the query on SQLFiddle.